# What is wrong with my code? Everytime I run it, my csv file won't write. The first time it did, then it doesn't :/

Tags: python, csv, overwrite, file-writing

This is the People-Counting-in-Real-Time-master code i get from github that i'm trying to use for my project. I've changed the cv function from this :

```
    if not args.get("input", False):
        print("[INFO] Starting the live stream..")
        vs = VideoStream(config.url).start()
        time.sleep(2.0)
```

to this :

```
    if not args.get("input", False):
        print("[INFO] Starting the live stream..")
        vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
        time.sleep(2.0)
```

But then my Log.csv wont write the data. The code i use is below :

```
        if config.Log:
            datetimee = [datetime.datetime.now()]
            d = [datetimee, empty1, empty, x]
            export_data = zip_longest(*d, fillvalue = '')

            with open('Log.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
                wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                wr.writerow(("End Time", "In", "Out", "Total Inside"))
                wr.writerows(export_data)
```

I've tried this line also but it didn't work

```
        if config.Log:
            datetimee = [datetime.datetime.now()]
            d = [datetimee, empty1, empty, x]
            export_data = zip_longest(*d, fillvalue = '')
            
            try:
                with open('Log.csv', 'r') as check:
                    pass
            except FileNotFoundError:
                with open('Log.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
                    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                    wr.writerow(("End Time", "In", "Out", "Total Inside"))
                    wr.writerows(export_data)
```

Please help me i'm malding and I need to present it next week D:

Comment: You're going to need to do some debugging here to see what's actually working, as your "doesn't work" explanation is lacking a *lot* of technical detail.

Comment: What I meant is it still doesn't write the csv. I've tried giving my friend the same exact thing, but it writes the csv in his computer after he runs the program. So i don't know what is the problem here, is it my coding or something else. Here is the repo https://github.com/saimj7/People-Counting-in-Real-Time/blob/master/Run.py

--- Ok I have found the problem. Hahaha Thanks for the advice brother